# Clarifying distinction between genetic recombination , translocation. and transposition

Tags: genetics, molecular-genetics, recombination

Having thought about the distinciton between these terms I have come up with the following definitions, are these correct?

**Translocation** describes the relocation of a chromosomal segment to a different position in the genome.

**Recombination** is the same except:

- it usually describes a non-pathological process involving balanced, reciprocal relocation of homologous DNA segments. Translocation is its accidental counterpart.
- Translocation usually related to endogenous DNA. Recombination is a broader term that can describe the incorporation of external DNA in bacteria such as transformation or transduction.
- The term can be used even more broadly to include independant assortment, which also effectivley acts to "Reshuffle" genetic material.

**Transposition:**

- essentially a special case of translocation which occurs as a result of transposase enzymes acting on mobile genetic elements.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Translocation is a mutation . Others are not necessarily .
By the way do not confuse those 3 terms with transversion and transition mutations.

***Translocation*** refers to 2 concepts :

1. In protein localizing during/after transcription

[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein_targeting)

[article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304415701000053)

2. A type of mutation in a chromosome

[Chromosomal Translocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromosomal_translocation#/media/File:Translocation-4-20.png)

(this is about the latter)

> Translocation describes the relocation of a chromosomal segment to a
> different position in the genome.

To some extent yes. Also It is a type of *mutation* . It does not happen normally and it is a result of malfunctioning proteins, mutagens etc. *More importantly* Translocation happens

- a) between two nonhomologous chromosomes
- b) between one chromosome and itself (it moves to a different locus
  of the same chromosome)

**See : Campbell biology 9th.ed.2011 Chapter 15 figure 15-14**

you can say that
**Translocation of DNA segments between homologous chromosomes has a specific name ("duplication")**. Keep in mind that most of the times we do not consider a movement of DNA to a homologous DNA a "translocation" as noted above.

***Recombination*** is a new combination of 2 DNA . Two DNA s become one. I believe the difference between Translocation and Recombination is that Translocation usually involves a huge amount of DNA (a lot of genes) compared to Recombintation ( probably not more than 10 genes or so)
I also agree with your statements on recombination. Here's more :

> it usually describes a non-pathological process

Recombination happens in several ways. We have recombination resulted from DNA repair, recombination from Cross-over during meiosis, artificial lab DNA recombination (in vitro) and also recombination by some viruses during infection ( Recall Lysogenic cycles and retroviruses) or other vectors.
Therefore recombination CAN happen in pathologic and non-pathologic procedures.

***See: Molecular Cell Biology Lodish et al 8th ed Section 5.6 "DNA repair and Recombination"
See T. L. Orr-Weaver and J. W. Szostak, 1985, Microbiol. Rev. 49:33.***

> Transposition:
> essentially a special case of translocation which occurs as a result of transposase enzymes acting on mobile genetic elements

Correct. Still I'm quite sure that we DO NOT use the term "Translocation" but instead "Recombination" for transposition.

a special case of ***Recombination*** which occurs as a result of transposase enzymes acting on mobile genetic elements.

Transposition involoves 2 or 3 genes and also it is not a type of mutation. So it is not a translocation.

***See: Molecular Cell Biology Lodish et al 8th ed Section 8.3 "Transposable (Mobile) DNA Elements"***

Comment: Thank you for adding some links. Please also explicitly indicate which of the sources each of your quotes comes from. Thanks

Comment: I'll keep that in mind. Still I'm not quite sure how to refer to a textbook in a correct way

Comment: Thanks, @sam, for the effort and improvements! You can refer to a textbook anyway that you deem appropriate. Just make sure when you're quoting something (in any context, really), that you include the origin of the quote in some way. Good edits :) +1